# URL analogue of $_FILES

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code from the **WordPress** meta like this →

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['video-url'] ) && ! empty( $_FILES['video-url'] ) ) {
```

But in case it is not a file but URl THEN WAHT SHOULD WE USE?

```
$_URL or
$_PATH or
```

or something else. because my plugin in WordPress this time has a URL, not file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `uri = $_REQUEST['field_name']`

I guess ... this should cover both POST and GET

Comment: Oh Ok. So insteadof $_FILES I should use $_REQUEST, Right sir?